# It does not detect cordova but it is installed and other projects work correctly

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, ionic3

I do not understand what may be happening. I have other projects in IONIC working correctly, but for some reason when trying to generate the Android version of this I get this error. All the answers I find are for people who do not have Android Studio / Gradle installed, but this is not the case

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
studio
(node:9388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:150:18)
    at StudioBuilder.prepEnv (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js:216:23)
    at Api.module.exports.run (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:154:20)
    at D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:342:43
    at _fulfilled (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\Clientes\proj\eComerce Ropa\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
(node:9388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting
a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: have you tried to remove android platform for the project and add it again?

Comment: yes with ionic cordova platform remove android and  ionic cordova platform add android